# D2C message using IoT Hub

Tags: azure, iot

I’d like to ask you a favor. I do have a problem confirming previously readed D2C message using IoT Hub. I am using REST API to pick up message like (I have replace SIG)

Request:

```
GET https://iot-hub-pospa.azure-devices.net/devices/18596c88-01e6-3f16-427b-10028d7305c5/messages/devicebound?api-version=2015-08-15-preview HTTP/1.1
IoTHub-MessageLockTimeout: 3600
Accept: application/json
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=iot-hub-pospa.azure-devices.net&sig={sig}&se=1485558838&skn=iothubowner
Host: iot-hub-pospa.azure-devices.net
If-None-Match: "1c5006a4-2288-4a2f-b7ea-dcdf9b5bbc99"
Connection: Close
X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.1
X-P2P-PeerDistEx: MinContentInformation=1.0, MaxContentInformation=2.0
Accept-Encoding: peerdist
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 35
ETag: "dfc78580-d251-4156-a5f6-c2a30811a504"
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
iothub-messageid: 02cdb012-9749-48a9-bfb3-5812a4740675
iothub-to: /devices/18596c88-01e6-3f16-427b-10028d7305c5/messages/deviceBound
iothub-expiry: 
iothub-correlationid: 
iothub-ack: full
iothub-sequencenumber: 56
iothub-enqueuedtime: 2/2/2016 9:57:34 AM
iothub-deliverycount: 0
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 10:21:43 GMT
Connection: close

2/2/2016 10:57:34 AM - Test message
```

Then when confirming I am getting HTTP 412 like

Request:

```
DELETE https://iot-hub-pospa.azure-devices.net/devices/18596c88-01e6-3f16-427b-10028d7305c5/messages/devicebound/02cdb012-9749-48a9-bfb3-5812a4740675?api-version=2015-08-15-preview HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
If-Match: "02cdb012-9749-48a9-bfb3-5812a4740675"
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=iot-hub-pospa.azure-devices.net&sig={sig}&se=1485558838&skn=iothubowner
Host: iot-hub-pospa.azure-devices.net
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
Content-Length: 330
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
iothub-errorcode: DeviceMessageLockLost
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 10:21:49 GMT
Connection: close
 
{"Message":"ErrorCode:DeviceMessageLockLost;Message 02cdb012-9749-48a9-bfb3-5812a4740675 lock was lost for Device 18596c88-01e6-3f16-427b-10028d7305c5\r\nTracking Id:05994074a3664933a0910b5fc70e04e5-G:GatewayWorkerRole.6-B:1-P:cffe397b-f627-4435-bd54-48f5ba79c3ca-TimeStamp:02/02/2016 10:21:49\r\nErrorCode:DeviceMessageLockLost"}
```

Does anybody know what should I do to successfully confirm/delete message from IoT Hub, please? Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the code is readable?

Answer (score 0):

```
     static DeviceClient _deviceClient;
     _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(<IoTHubURI>, TransportType.Http1);   

 public void SendMessage(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message message = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message();
        try
        {
            foreach (var r in dictionary)
            {
                message.Properties[r.Key] = r.Value.ToString();
            }
            _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```